# Limit $\lim_\limits{x\to0} \frac{\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-x}{\tan^3(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the given limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)-x}{\tan^3(x)} .$$

I've tried to evaluate it but I always get stuck... Obviously I need L'Hôpital's Rule here, but still get confused on the way. May someone show me what is the trick here?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need l'Hospital 3 times.

Comment: $\ln(x + \sqrt{1+x^2}) = \sinh^{-1} x$

Comment: what do you exactly get confused with? show what you did so that you get help *exactly* on the issue you do not understand.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that
$$\text{arsinh } x := \ln\left(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}\right),$$
and that it has a nice Taylor series expansion:
$$\text{arsinh } x \sim x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{x^3}{3} + R_1(x),$$
where $R_1(x) \in O(x^4)$.
(it's not too hard to write the coefficients in a closed form, but we only need the first terms here).

Accounting for the subtracted $x$ in the numerator of the original ratio, the Taylor series of the numerator is
$$- \frac{1}{6} x^3 + R(x),$$
where $R_1 (x) \in O(x^4)$.

> Now, the Taylor series of $\tan x$ is$$\tan x \sim x + \frac{1}{3} x^3 + \cdots.$$ So, multiplying gives that the Taylor series of the denominator $\tan^3 x$ is $$x^3 + R_2(x),$$ where $R_2(x) \in O(x^4)$.
> The leading terms of the numerator and denominator are both third-order, so the limit is the ratio of the coefficients of those terms, that is $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}) - x}{\tan^3 x} = \frac{\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}{(1)} = -\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 3):

i will use the maclaurin expansion for $\sqrt{1+x}, \ln(1+x), \tan(x)$

$\begin{align}
\ln[x + (1 + x^2)^{1/2}] &= \ln[x + 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 -\frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots]\\
&=\ln(1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots)  \\
&=(x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots)-\frac{1}{2} \{x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots\}^2 \\
&+ \frac{1}{3}\{x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots\}^3  \cdots\\
&=(x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8}x^4 + \cdots)-\frac{x^2}{2} (1 + x + \cdots) +  \frac{1}{3}(x^3  + \cdots) +\cdots\\
&=x-\frac{1}{2}x^3 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \cdots\\
&= x-\frac{1}{6}x^3 + \cdots
\end{align}$

the expansion for 
$$\tan x = x + \cdots$$  putting the two together

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\ln[x + (1 + x^2)^{1/2}] - x}{\tan^3 x} = -\dfrac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on no l'Hospital rule nor Taylor expansion. The following standard limits only are used:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^{x} &=&1. \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} &=&1. \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}-e^{x}}{x^{3}} &=&-\frac{1}{6}%
. \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}{x^{3}} &=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}

We transform the original expression $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln (x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}})-x}{\tan
^{3}x}$ as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&\frac{x^{3}}{\tan ^{3}x}\cdot \dfrac{\ln (x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}})-\ln e^{x}}{%
x^{3}} \\
&=&\frac{x^{3}}{\tan ^{3}x}\cdot \dfrac{\ln (\dfrac{x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{e^{x}})}{%
x^{3}} \\
&=&\frac{x^{3}}{\tan ^{3}x}\cdot \dfrac{\ln (1+\color{red}{u(x)})}{\color{red}{u(x)}}\cdot \dfrac{\color{red}{\dfrac{%
x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-e^{x}}{e^{x}}}}{x^{3}},\ \ \ with\ \color{red}{u(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-e^{x}}{e^{x}}}  \\
&=&\left( \frac{x}{\tan x}\right) ^{3}\cdot \dfrac{\ln (1+u(x))}{u(x)}\cdot 
\dfrac{1}{e^{x}}\cdot \left( \left( \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\color{green}{-1-\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}}{%
x^{3}}\right) +\left( \frac{\color{blue}{1}+x\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}}-e^{x}}{x^{3}}\right)
\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}u(x)=0$,  and the function $t\rightarrow t^3$ is continuous, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}})-x}{\tan ^{3}x} &=&\left(
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\tan x}\right) ^{3}\cdot \lim_{u\rightarrow 0}%
\frac{\ln (1+ u)}{u}\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{x}} \\
&&\cdot \left( \left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}-1-\frac{1}{2}%
x^{2}}{x^{3}}\right) +\left( \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1+x+\frac{1}{2}%
x^{2}-e^{x}}{x^{3}}\right) \right)  \\
&=&\left( 1\right) ^{3}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{1}\cdot \left( \left( 0\right)
+\left( -\frac{1}{6}\right) \right)  \\
&=&\color{red}{-\frac{1}{6}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hi, the third and fourth 'standard limits' used here require division by 0 , taking the limit of x^3 as x approaches 0. How are these two limits calculated? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without Taylor, applying L'Hospital once:

The derivative of the numerator is $$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-1=\frac{1-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=-\frac{x^2}{(1+\sqrt{x^2+1})\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$ Taking away the factors that tend to one, it can be simplified as $$-\frac{x^2}2.$$

The derivative of the denominator is 
$$3(\tan x)'\tan^2 x=3(\tan^2x+1)\tan^2x,$$
It can be simplified as 
$$3\tan^2x.$$

Now the limit is that of $$-\frac{x^2}{6\tan^2x}=-\frac16\left(\frac {\cos x}{\sin x}x\right)^2=-\frac16\cos^2x\left(\frac x{\sin x}\right)^2,$$
hence $$-\frac16.$$
Note: if you distrust the simplifications, you can keep all factors and split the limit as the product of two, one indeterminate (zero factors) and the other determinate (unit factors).

Answer (score 1):

L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-x}{\tan^3(x)}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{\tan^3 x}{x^3}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})-x)'}{(x^3)'}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x^2}{3x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})}=-\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

Hence it will be in $\frac{0}{0}$ form and then apply L'Hospital's rule  3 times

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here seems to be put $t = \log(x + \sqrt{1 + x^{2}})$ so that $$x + \sqrt{1 + x^{2}} = e^{t}, \sqrt{1 + x^{2}} - x = e^{-t}$$ and finally $$x = \frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2} = \sinh t$$ Further note that $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sinh t}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2t} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac{e^{t} - 1}{t} + \frac{e^{-t} - 1}{-t}\right) = 1$$We can now proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(x + \sqrt{1 + x^{2}}) - x}{\tan^{3}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(x + \sqrt{1 + x^{2}}) - x}{x^{3}}\cdot\frac{x^{3}}{\tan^{3}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(x + \sqrt{1 + x^{2}}) - x}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - \sinh t}{\sinh^{3}t}\text{ (putting }x = \sinh t)\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - \sinh t}{t^{3}}\cdot\frac{t^{3}}{\sinh^{3}t}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t - \sinh t}{t^{3}}\tag{1}\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1 - \cosh t}{3t^{2}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{-2\sinh^{2}(t/2)}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{2}{3}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sinh^{2}(t/2)}{4(t/2)^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\notag\\
&= \text{(continue from equation (1))}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{t - \left(t + \dfrac{t^{3}}{6} + o(t^{3})\right)}{t^{3}}\text{ (using Taylor series for }\sinh t)\notag\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\notag
\end{align}
The problem can't be solved without use of LHR or Taylor. Moreover if we go for LHR, only one application is sufficient.